# How to check all fields are valid?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

This code checks each element is valid or not and it appends css class depends on its situation. 
If the element is valid, it removes disabled tag from submit button (blocksender).

But, 
When some element is valid and some element is invalid
if you focusout from a valid element, the submit button is enabled. It's a problem.

How to check all elements? and if they are all valid, i can enable the submit button.

```
$(document).on('focusout', 'input.validate, textarea.validate', function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass('is_required') || $(this).val().length)
    {

        var result = window['validate_'+$(this).attr('data-validate')]($(this).val())

        if (result)
        {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('form-error').addClass('form-ok');
            $(".blocksender").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");

        }
        else
        {
            $(this).parent().addClass('form-error').removeClass('form-ok');
            $(".blocksender").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    }
});
```

This is from validate.js in Prestashop 1.6 and I use it in contact_form.tpl something like that:

```
<input class="validate is_required" type="text" id="email" name="from" data-validate="isEmail"/>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should loop through all the form elements, to check whether they're valid. In your code you check only the actual input element: `if ($(this)...`. In your case should be something like: `$('#form input').each(function() { if ($(this)...` Also, you may remove one "disabled" from this part - **.removeAttr("disabled", "disabled")**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would count the number of elements with the error class: if it's 0, enable button, if not, disable it

```
$(document).on('focusout', 'input.validate, textarea.validate', function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass('is_required') || $(this).val().length)
    {

        var result = window['validate_'+$(this).attr('data-validate')]($(this).val())

        if (result)
        {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('form-error').addClass('form-ok');

            // There's the chance of no errors, check it.
            var numItems = $('.form-error').length;// Check number of elements with class error.

            if(numItems === 0) {// If all items are ok, remove disable.
               $(".blocksender").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        }
        else// There's at least one error, no need to check, disable it.
        {
            $(this).parent().addClass('form-error').removeClass('form-ok');
            $(".blocksender").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    }
});
```